Want to debunk claim of robotic movement using magnets
A friend of mine claims to have a patent pending on a type of robotic movement that involves magnets on a motorized miniature tank treadmill running inside a completely enclosed box. The magnets on the treads are attracted to a series of iron bars embedded inside a table, which are hidden under paint. He claims the attraction between the moving magnets on the treads inside the box and the iron bars in the table cause the entire box to move forward. He has demonstrated this movement, but I think it's a hoax and he's just using a moving magnet under the table to move the box. Newton's Second Law would appear to negate any movement of the box with an internal treadmill, as the magnets should just move past the iron bars in the table below without creating any movement, because of the opposing forces of the tank moving forward against the interior of the box and the moving treads on the bottom of the box.
Am I correct in being suspicious of this, and how can I debunk it? Thank you for any input.
I tried inspecting the box, and it appears to be arranged as claimed. However, I was not allowed to inspect the table as closely as I wanted to.

An internal system cannot cause external motion without ejecting something (which is not occurring here). Momentum is conserved. This is clearly a hoax.

Can you at least include a diagram?

Is the internal treadmill motorized? If yes, then the box doesn't violate Newton's laws in any way. Just like a car's tires generate traction with the road through adhesive forces, this box could generate traction with the table through magnetic forces.

Yes, the internal treadmill is motorized.  Magnets attached to the treadmill run in a loop around the treadmill.  They are supposedly attracted to iron bars embedded in the table below the box, which are spaced to match the spacing of the magnets on the treadmill, so magnetic attraction to other metal doesn't interfere with the traction between the internal magnets and the external iron bars in the table.   I just feel that some law regarding closed systems is being violated here.

Well, clearly, it is unlikely that a conservation law is being violated. The secret probably lies in the mechanical details of its design.

Anything powered by magnets being attracted to iron bars would work until the magnets reach the iron bars. Then they would stick and there would be no further movement. Is this what you see?
Are you saying this attraction is supposed to power the robot indefinitely. This would not work.
It is hard anything definite to say without a diagram.

There is a small motorized treadmill inside a small box, with magnets being pulled around the internal treadmill in a loop.  In the table below the box, iron bars have allegedly been embedded, spaced so they match the spacing of the magnets on the treadmill.  I just feel some law regarding closed systems or law regarding friction is being violated here.

You should edit the question with what you said here. That clarifies things. This is possible.

It is well-known that "magnetic motors" using various arrangements of magnets, pieces of iron, and rotating parts do not work. A proof I have seen (but for which I cannot remember the original citation) asserts that this fundamental fact itself stems from the mathematical fact that the divergence of a permanent magnet field is zero.
Another fundamental fact is that for every action, there is a reaction: that is, forces come in pairs. This means that it is impossible for an object to set itself into motion without anything to push against, which is in accord with your intuition.
Note here that people all around the world have competed for years to construct machines which appear to violate this action/reaction law. In each case, the source of energy which drives the machine has been deliberately (and cleverly!) hidden so as to be invisible to even careful observers, whose task it is to then identify the hidden energy source.
In any case, being prohibited from taking the device apart can in practice be taken as proof positive that it is a clever trick- nothing more.

It's not a perpetual motion machine.  A small motorized treadmill inside an enclosed box with magnets embedded in the treads are being pulled around in a loop, like tank treads.  Iron bars embedded in the table below the box are spaced so they match the spacing of the magnets of the treadmill inside the box.  I just feel that some law regarding closed systems or laws regarding friction are being violated here to achieve the effect my friend claims.
